# create n dataframes in a for loop with an extra column with a specific number in it

Tags: dataframe

[image]

Hi all I have a dataframe like that shown in the picture:

I am trying to create 2 different dataframes with the same "hour", "minute", "value" (and value.1 respectively) columns, by adding also column with number 0 and 1 respectively). I would like to do it in a for loop as I want to create n dataframe (not just 2 shown here).

I tried something like this but it's not working (error: KeyError: "['value.i'] not in index"):

```
for i in range(1):
 series[i] = df_new[['hour', 'minute', 'value.i']]
 series[i].insert(0, 'number', 'i')
```

can you help me ?
thannks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from what I have understood you want to make value.i to show value.1 or value.2

```
for i in range(1):
   # f is for the format so can interpret i as variable only
   series[i] = df_new[['hour','minute',f'value.{i}']]
```